# DMS-59 Video Card

Tags: graphics-card, vga

I want a video card for a Dell Optiplex 755 that supports two monitors.

There are two desirable ways for me to do this: I could get a video card with dual-head VGA ports or a video card with a DMS-59 port. I'd really like the DMS-59 but I can't find a list anywhere of which video cards have one.

So, my question is: Is there any database out there that make searching for video cards easier?

I want a database of all or most video cards where I can query the database to filter the results just to show what I want. I want a list of all the video cards that either have two VGA ports or one DMS-59 port that are compatible with my desktop.

Comment: This is so close to a shopping request without actually saying it as I think I've ever seen.

Comment: What's wrong with dual DVI?  Is this low profile?  You could get away with dual DisplayPort or mini-DisplayPort, in that case.  (I don't know if there is such a beast, to be fair, but there's certainly a quad-mini-DP low profile card on the market so I have to think dual is available.)

Comment: My monitors to not support DisplayPort. And there's nothing wrong with dual DVI, I didn't ask anything about DMS-59 or Dual DVI, my question was: "Is there any database out there that makes searching for video cards easier?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple web search of "[video card dms-59](https://www.google.com/search?q=video%20card%20dms-59)" results in several shopping recommendations that include the specified requirement. I have not heard of a website that provides a database such as you describe.

You won't find such a database probably because the video card market is extremely fast moving. A video card may only have a couple months of active marketing before it's discontinued in favor of different flavors and models. Only a few video cards last longer that a few months on store shelves. The vast majority of older cards are not kept around as lower budget cards because even budget buyers want current architecture, and the video card manufacturers are able to meet their desired price points, from extreme to budget, while keeping the architectures up to date, so the old cards are simply discarded rather than pushed down the pile.

A search for video card databases results in straight lists with only minimal sorting capability. So no, I do not think there is a list of all DMS-59 video cards, but through a simple google query, we can find a list of cards meeting your criteria.